# Correct word order in "what that's for"

Tags: word-order

I've just read the following sentence in a book:

> I wonder what that's for?

So is that correct order of words "that" and "is"? In my opinion there should be:

> I wonder what's that for?

Am I right? Or might it be both variants are possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be written this way:

> I wonder what that's for.

or

> "I wonder, 'What's that for?'"

The first one is a statement and "what that's for" is the subordinate clause; therefore, it's not actually posing a question.  The second one with a question mark and quotations is someone thinking out loud.  He's questioning ***what that is for*** by asking himself the question, ***"What is that for?"***

I hope that might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck.

Comment: Nick, I like this answer and your polite and encouraging comments at the end.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help.